# SQL query: multiply count() IF another value = x

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working on a query to count instances of duplicates and sort them for a leaderboard.

What I am trying to do is

- count occurances of that owner (id). IF that "rarity" column of that row is 2, I want it to count as 10. If it's 3, it should count as 100.

Example of working count (that does not multiply) I started from:

```
SELECT owner, COUNT(*) AS 'count'
FROM 'usercards' AS 'usercards' WHERE ('usercards'.'group' LIKE '%$group%' AND 'usercards'.'customCard' = 0 AND 'usercards'.'rarity' = 1)
GROUP BY owner
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

here is another example of what I have tried. I have many more examples that have not worked.

```
SELECT rarity, owner
FROM 'usercards' AS 'usercards' WHERE ('usercards'.'group' LIKE '%$group%' AND 'usercards'.'customCard' = 0)
IF (rarity = 1)
SELECT (COUNT(*) * 1) AS 'count'
FROM 'usercards' AS 'usercards' WHERE ('usercards'.'group' LIKE '%$group%' AND 'usercards'.'customCard' = 0)
GROUP BY owner
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

I'm trying to do this in SQL because it should be faster than node.

Non-working sollutions:

- POWER(M,N); not avalible in SQlite.

  SELECT owner, rarity,
  COUNT(*) AS 'count',
  CASE
  WHEN rarity = 1 THEN COUNT(*)
  WHEN rarity = 2 THEN COUNT(*) * 10
  WHEN rarity = 3 THEN COUNT(*) * 100
  END AS 'modifiedCount'
  FROM 'usercards' AS 'usercards'
  WHERE 'usercards'.'group' LIKE '%$group%' AND 'usercards'.'customCard' = 0
  GROUP BY owner, rarity
  ORDER BY count DESC;
- Doesn't work, it multiplies ALL results by 1 / 10 / 100 based on the value of the first result.

Note: I am using SQlite

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT owner,
       SUM(CASE rarity WHEN 2 THEN 10 WHEN 3 THEN 100 ELSE 1 END) count
FROM usercards
WHERE `group` LIKE '%$group%' AND customCard = 0
GROUP BY owner
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the structure of your table, but looks like the [MySQL POWER function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-power-function.php) is what you're needing.

```
POWER(M,N);
```

With what you describe (rarity 2 = 10, rarity 3 = 100) then you're using a power/exponent of the form

*"10 to the power of rarity - 1"*

(So 10^0 = 1, 10^1 = 10, 10^2 = 100, 10^3 = 1000).

To achieve a multiplication on the "counts" then you'd use something like this:

```
SELECT owner, COUNT(*) * POWER(10, rarity - 1) FROM `usercards`  AS 'usercards' WHERE ....
```

You'll need to decide how to approach the SELECT part of the query based on your table structure and conditions, as well as the GROUP BY clauses.

Comment: That's smart, I would have never thought of this.
Maybe POWER is not a thing is SQlite? Either way, this did the same as normal count when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a [case statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) for conditionally multiplying based on the value of another column.

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT owner, rarity,
       COUNT(*) AS 'count', 
       CASE 
           WHEN rarity = 1 THEN COUNT(*) 
           WHEN rarity = 2 THEN COUNT(*) * 10 
           WHEN rarity = 3 THEN COUNT(*) * 100 
       END AS 'modifiedCount'
FROM 'usercards' AS 'usercards' 
WHERE 'usercards'.'group' LIKE '%$group%' AND 'usercards'.'customCard' = 0
GROUP BY owner, rarity
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: My bad I made a typo.
This works, as in it doesn't error! But the count seems to be the same. It reports the same number as the count without multiplication.

Comment: Have you checked the rarity isn't 1 for every row?

Comment: Oh. Well:
Here's what happens, it seems to apply the multiplication to all of the rows (despite many of them being rarity 1.), when it sees that rarity is 2. Probably because the first one it found was rarity 2?

So the reason I thought it didn't multiply all of them, is because the ones that i saw were all multiplied by 1.
But in that

Comment: So you got it working?

Comment: No. I did not. It always multiples by 1/10/100 based on whichever came first.